# How to Protect/Encrypt MongoDB Data

Tags: node.js, mongodb, encryption

I have an existing NodeJS app that allows users to store personal information in a mongo database. This data must be encrypted in some form, or at least not tied to a particular user.

I was planning on using the [NPM mongoose-encryption package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-encryption), but it doesn't work with updating fields. Right now, passwords are hashed with a salt and both are stored in the user document. I was thinking another option could be hashing the user id and using that to associate other docs with the user. This way, if there is a security breach, the data will be unusable without knowing which user it belongs to.

Any thoughts/recommendation on this? What is the best way to protect users  personally identifiable information?

Answer (score 0):

Hashing user id or username might not be a good idea, it is ok for user login. but it might bring more pains when u trying to do some aggregation or statistics on the stored data, every time you make a query related to user id, u might need to hash it first and then construct the query.

Besides, user id/username column becomes unsortable and it is hard to build index on top of it, since hashing is not invertible.

Just my personal thinking.